# How to call a function while a indeterminate material dialog is in progress?

Tags: java, android

Right now i am using [Material Dialog](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) in my application like this:

```
dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .title("Please Wait")
            .content("Loading")
            .progress(true, 0)
            .titleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey))
            .widgetColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey))
            .progressIndeterminateStyle(true)
            .show();
```

I want to call the function in the background while progress bar is running 
like for example  address() is the function name now where should i call this function ?

I have tried using determinate progress dialog box but it didn't worked as i thought

```
while (dialog.getCurrentProgress() != dialog.getMaxProgress()) {
// If the progress dialog is cancelled (the user closes it before it's done), break the loop
if (dialog.isCancelled()) break;
// Wait 50 milliseconds to simulate doing work that requires progress
try {
    Thread.sleep(50);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    break;
}
// Increment the dialog's progress by 1 after sleeping for 50ms
dialog.incrementProgress(1);}
```

This is what i am calling in a function but it returns a null value for the first time because it takes time to mobile GPS to send lat lng. I want that this function should be done in background while progress dialog is being shown till this function returns a non null value.

```
private void Address() {
```

gps.getLocation();

```
        if (gps.canGetLocation == false) {

            // Here you can ask the user to try again, using return; for that
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //return;
        } else {

            // Getting location co-ordinates
            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            //   Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude:" + latitude + " | Longitude: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            address = gps.getLocationAddress();
            street = gps.getLocationArea();
            String[] compare = {"Jawahar Nagar", "Tilak Nagar", "Sector 4", "Adarsh Nagar", "Gurunanakpura",
                    "Raja Park", "Janta Colony", "Jhalana Doongri", "Sector 5", "Sector 1", "Sector 2", "Sector 3", "Sector 6", "Sector 7"};
            if (Arrays.asList(compare).contains(street) && address.equals("null")) {
                int zip = Integer.parseInt("302004");
                address = String.valueOf(zip);


            }

        }}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You want to have an indeterminate progressbar and check if it's progressing or what? Do you know what indeterminate means?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the `Dialog` and use the reference for showing and dismissing. You also have to set `cancelable` as false.

e.g. like this

```
dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .title("Please Wait")
            .content("Loading")
            .progress(true, 0)
            .titleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey))
            .widgetColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey))
            .progressIndeterminateStyle(true)
            .cancelable(false)
            .build();
```

Your method `address()` could look like this

```
dialog.show();
// do logic
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do background process in android. Example :

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     MaterialDialog dialog;
     protected void onPreExecute () {
       dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .title("Please Wait")
            .content("Loading")
            .progress(true, 0)
            .titleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey))
            .widgetColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey))
            .progressIndeterminateStyle(true)
            .show();
     }

     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         dialog.dismiss();
     }
 }
```

Then in your method to call your dialog :

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Your background process goes to doInBackground method.

Comment: the thing is i want to progress dialog to keep running till i get a valid result.

Comment: the thing is i am calling this address function which contains user address tracking code through gps. Now gps is taking time to calulate the lat lng and till the time it is calculated i want that this progress dialog should be running.This code is working but the function sends a null value for the first time and from the second time it works well.Can you tell how to return a non null value in address.Check my edit for more help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AsyncTask like this

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //Call the address() method

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Stop showing your progress bar
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Start showing your progress bar
    }

}
```

Comment: the thing is i am calling this address function which contains user address tracking code through gps. Now gps is taking time to calculate the lat lng and till the time it is calculated i want that this progress dialog should be running.This code is working but the function sends a null value for the first time and from the second time it works well.Can you tell how to return a non null value in address.Check my edit for more help!!

Comment: @HimanshuDaswani If the address is the required field for you than you can recall the getAddress() from onPostExecute() when you get the null address and don't stop the progress dialog until you get the address.

Comment: you mean i should call Address(); function two times one in do in background and another in post execute method?

Comment: @HimanshuDaswani ya if you don't get the address in doInBackground than on the onPostExecute you can retry to get it.

Comment: it solved my problem but it created another bug now  when i turn off gps and start the app and it asks to turn it on and when click on yes to turn on gps then address function is not working at all and when i restart the app keeping gps on it does the work beautifully.

Comment: @HimanshuDaswani I will definitely help you but you need to post this as a separate question as it's not related to this one. And ya don't forget to accept the answer if you satisfy with the answer.

Comment: it solved the problem but it created another gps bug which was not before. I will definitely accept this answer if you can completely help me in solving my problem. Your solution solved the problem but created GPS problem.